# Leaflet tileLayer canvas, overlapping canvas opacity when zooming

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, maps, leaflet

I want to darken a map and lighten the area around the point of interest and I'm using Leaflet's tileLayer.canvas for that.

This is what it looks like:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epvJVJ?editors=101

```
var center = L.latLng(51.505, -0.09);

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { attribution: osmAttrib }).addTo(map);

var tiles = L.tileLayer.canvas();


function darken() {
  tiles.drawTile = function (canvas, tile, zoom) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var tileSize = this.options.tileSize;
    var point = center;
    var start = tile.multiplyBy(tileSize);
    var p = map.project(point);

    var x = Math.round(p.x - start.x);
    var y = Math.round(p.y - start.y);

    var radius = 20;

    context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)';
    context.fill();
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.clip();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.restore();
  }
};

darken();
map.addLayer(tiles);
```

The problem is whenever I scroll, the new canvas is drawn and overlaps the old canvas for a moment before the old canvas is removed. Is there any way to make that go smoother? Or is it possible to make something like a reverse-marker that colors everything except the specified area?

Thanks in advance.